# pct_estimate and pct_adjusted in FiveThirtyEight polling data

Tags: elections, polling

I'm working on polling data from fivethirtyeight[1](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-primary-data/pres_primary_avgs_2020.csv%22). What is the meaning of pct_trend_adjusted column here? What are they adjusting for?